# Error compiling gcc on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian): make: *** [bootstrap] error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, make, gcc, autoconf

I'm trying to compile the gcc version 2.95.3 on raspbian, I need it in order to compile the 2.6 kernel.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/5.1-pre1/LFS-BOOK-5.1-PRE1-HTML/chapter06/gcc-2953.html), but when I get to the bootstrapping step, i get

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
cd ../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc; autoconf
/bin/sh: autoconf: not found
make[1]: *** [../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/configure]
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you using GCC 2.95.3? This is a very old version of the compiler which is no longer supported. Is there some technical reason GCC 4.x will not work?

Comment: @DragonLord Yes there is. I get a lot of errors when I try to compile the kernel 2.6 with gcc 4, and many posts on SO say that you need gcc 2.95.3 in order to compile it. I'll try your answer ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/bin/sh: autoconf: not found
```

You're missing `autoconf`, which is necessary to compile GCC. To continue, try installing it using the package manager:

```
# apt-get install autoconf
```