# Error compiling gcc on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, compile, gcc, arm

So, after solving the problems I had before ([previous question here](https://superuser.com/questions/761075/error-compiling-gcc-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-make-bootstrap-error)), I'm having some other trouble compiling gcc 2.95.3 on my Raspberry.

This is what I get with the

```
make bootstrap
```

command.

```
../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/config/arm/arm.c: In function ‘arm_override_options’:
../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/config/arm/arm.c:286:20: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/config/arm/arm.c:530:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make[2]: *** [arm.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make[1]: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me? How can I make it compile?

---

**UPDATE**

After changing that variable name, I'm getting these errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
                 from ../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/libgcc2.c:41:
/usr/include/features.h:323: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:356: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/libgcc2.c:41:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:42: bits/waitflags.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/stdlib.h:43: bits/waitstatus.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/stdlib.h:320: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/libgcc2.c:42:
/usr/include/unistd.h:203: bits/posix_opt.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/unistd.h:207: bits/environments.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/unistd.h:218: bits/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../gcc-2.95.3/gcc/libgcc2.c:42:
/usr/include/unistd.h:606: bits/confname.h: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [libgcc2.a] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make[3]: *** [stmp-multilib-sub] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [stmp-multilib] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make[1]: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Desktop/gcc2/gcc-2-build/gcc'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you, this is an old problem. I too had it, and solved it by looking it up with Google.

In the file arm.c (/gcc/config/arm), line 530 as per the error message above,  correct the line as follows:

```
  arm_prgmode = TARGET_APCS_32 ? PROG_MODE_PROG32 : PROG_MODE_PROG26;
```

I have no idea how this silly mistake percolated into the code, and how it evaded detection. But alas, there it is.

EDIT:

The second error is not very specific, might be due to many factors. For instance, is your PATH variable empty?

```
  echo $PATH
```

If it echoes something like

```
  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

then you are Ok, otherwise

```
  export PATH= /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

will solve the problem.

Or you may need to install/re-install the *libc6-dev* libraries. In this case,

```
  sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev
  sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Alternatively, you may try to use (I found this very convenient) a pre-built tool-chain, available from here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools. Even if you know what you are doing, going through a seemingly endless list of compilation errors trying to identify all the pieces you are missing can be tiresome.

Comment: Nevermind. I was wrong. I was checking for `TARGET_APCS_32 ? PROG_MODE_PROG32 : PROG_MODE_PROG26;` to be there, but I didn't notice thet the variable name changes from `arm_prog_mode` to `arm_prgmode`. Thanks! Let's see if that compiles fine or if I get some other error

Comment: It has other errors. Can you please see my update?

Comment: @Harlandraka Please see the edit to my answer

Comment: How should I use the tools?

Comment: @Harlandraka Download the zip file (lower right hand side corner), unzip, install everything.

Comment: Yes, but what can I do with them? Will they help me compiling gcc 2.95.3? If yes, how?

Comment: @Harlandraka By providing all of the packages you are misisng.

Comment: So I install them, then re-configure gcc and remake bootstrap. Am I right?

Comment: @Harlandraka Yes.Hopefully.

Comment: Ok, I'm now transferring the file to the raspberry. I'll try it asap. Thank you!